# What functions are triggered after coming back to the application from other applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, background

In iOS4, users are able to leave the current application and put it into background by double-pushing the major button on the phone. I would like to know what functions will be invoked after coming back to my application after its being in the background.

I am thinking maybe some functions at the view controller or UIApplicationDelegate. Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the UIApplicationDelegate reference page and you'll find a method called -applicationWillEnterForeground:. The description of that method also points you to -applicationDidBecomeActive:.